# Get selected item from drop-down list where options filled

Tags: php

I've this code to get the name of files and add them to a drop-down list:

```
<?php
$dir = "uploads";
$dh = opendir($dir);
echo "<select name=case>"; 
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $name = (pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $ext == "jpg") 
    {
        echo "<option value=".$dir."/".$file .">" . $name . "</option>"; 
    }
}
echo "</select>"; 
closedir($dh);
?>
```

Now I'd like to add a submit button and print the file path (*value*) of the selected item from the drop-down list on the **same page**.

Comment: You should probably quote your attributes, just in case there's a space inside one of the filenames.

Comment: so add the form, submit to the same page, where are you have a problem?

Comment: @minitech; Thanks for the edit. How did you do that?

Comment: @Robertico: You just indent code blocks with four spaces (but make sure there's a blank line in front!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add an ID to your `<select>` element:

   ```
   echo "<select id='selCase' name='case'>";
   ```
2. Insert an element which will contain the selected value

   ```
   // After closedir($dh);
   echo "<div id='divOut'></div>";
   ```
3. Insert a snippet of JavaScript:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("ready", function () {
     document.getElementById("selCase").addEventListener("change", function () {
       var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
       document.getElementById("divOut").innerHTML = val;
     });
   });
   ```

**But** I would recommend you reading websites/books/tutorials about JavaScript development!